# How to improve performance of an angularjs app?

Tags: angularjs, performance

Something I'm having difficult time to understand. I'm working on an angularjs application which already has about 20 controllers and I'm not done yet, and several shared services. These do not necessarily do a lot of things, but separation, I thought, is important. Either way, what I wanted to know is what happens to the variables and scopes in these controllers when the route changes? I'm using `ui.router`. The controllers get the data from the database, so there are a lot of Arrays for different types of data. When I check the Profile in Chrome Dev Tools, the snapshot size seems to be increasing when I change routes even without entering any data in the input fields. I just don't want the apps to freeze up after a couple hours of use. The app will be used by 14 people and will run from 8:30 am to 9 pm every day. What sorts of things do I need to consider in order to increase the performance of the app?

Comment: You need to bring the `$scope` in the controllers so that you can hook into the deactivation event and then null out all the data references in the controller and remove the memory held.

Comment: Some things you need to check is that these controllers are getting deactivated. Also, you may not need to actually deactivate a controller - to have it cached may increase user experience

Comment: See this [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle)

Comment: If you don't do anything stupid like attach *(large)* values to global variables or leave event callbacks hanging, it should be fine. Angular will throw away the references to created controllers *(and do other teardown stuff)* and the GC will eventually kick in. If you can identify a bottleneck, you could maybe provide more specific info about it so we could take a look.

Comment: *what happens to the variables and scopes in these controllers when the route changes* - they are garbage-collected, unless you've done something that causes memory leaks. *What sorts of things do I need to consider in order to increase the performance of the app* - stick to one-time bindings whenever possible. The fact that you talk about 'controllers' so much suggests that the app suffers from fat controllers and needs refactoring. Controllers shouldn't 'get the data from the database', models (as in MVC) should.

Comment: Will the 14 people all be sharing the same browser/computer?

Comment: @estus, I have services for anything that I need to acquire data from. e.g., PatientService, PrescriberService, which is called by the respective controllers and CRUD is handled from the service. I have only 3 `$watchCollection` altogether. Controllers only have e.g., `vm.Claims = {}`, for which the data is obtained using service: `ClaimService.getClaims().then()`. The view uses `ng-repeat`. Some controllers may have other time/date or other calculations. Any data that needs to be shared is done using `ShareddataService`.

Comment: If the services aren't polluted with unnecessary data over time, you're on the safe side then, unless you have controllers that aren't destroyed on route change.